# Reduce Div width when scrolled down and bring it back when go on top through Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am hoping to reduce my div width when I scroll down but I want to bring it back up when the user scroll to the top. ( Top as in, 150 or less).

I tried the following code which works when I scroll down but doesn't work when I scroll to the top.

I am not sure what I am missing.

```
 $(document).scroll(function() { 

            var scrollPosition = $(this).scrollTop();


            if (scrollPosition <= 150) {

                $("div.mydiv").animate({
                    width : "20%"
                });
            }
            else {
                $("div.mydiv").animate({
                    width : "50px"
                });
            }

    });
```

Any idea what I am missing?

Thanks

Comment: **[Works fine here](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/qhhnu9rn/)** and with **[document too](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/qhhnu9rn/1/)**

Comment: replace document with window $(window).scroll(function(){....

Comment: Rao, it's definitely not working there when scrolled to the top. It doesn't come back to its original position when scrolled to the top. Wisd, it didn't work with window too.

Comment: You are using pixels and percentages, did you mean to set it to 50% instead of 50**px** ?

Comment: No that's correct. Actually that works fine too. The problem is `width : "20%"`. When I scroll to the top and when I want the div to come back to its original position the first condition doesn't make the div to 20%. It stays at 50px for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```js
$(window).scroll(function() { 
 var scrollPosition = $(this).scrollTop();
 if (scrollPosition <= 150) {
  if($("div.mydiv").is(":animated")){
  }else{
   $("div.mydiv").animate({
    width : "20%"
   },100);
  }
 } else {
  if($("div.mydiv").is(":animated")){
  }else{
  $("div.mydiv").animate({
   width : "50px"
   },100);
  }
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mydiv" style="width:20%;height:1500px;border:1px solid black">DIV TEST</div>
```